# Dynamically change size of UIWebview based on content

Tags: xcode, swift, uiwebview

I am presenting blog posts in a UIWebview.  How can I dynamically change the Webview to properly fit the content?  I would like the height of the Webview to scale so that there is no need to scroll within the Webview.

Thanks!

Comment: so what, the text is really small, or the web view is in another scrollable container? the web view should just change to the frame size is equal to the content size?

Comment: The text size is fine.  But there is too much text which results in the user having to scroll within the webview.  If the webview doesn't fit on the screen and must scroll the entire parent view, this would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait until the web view calls the delegate to say that the load is complete, then take the content size and update the frame.

Or you could use KVO to observe the content size and each time it updates you can update the frame.

Comment: Yes... I think your first suggestion will work perfectly.

Cheers!